# kura cannot connect to aws iot : device ssl exception

Tags: aws-iot, kura

I have been trying to connect the eclipse kura to AWS IOT platform but not able to connect. I have referred this documentation https://eclipse.github.io/kura/cloud/kura-aws-cloud.html. Everything works untill i try to configure SSl parameters through kura web UI. After entering the Correct values for the storage-alias, private key and certificate it gives me the following exception :

```
ErrorLogger INFO:
ILLEGAL_ARGUMENTorg.eclipse.kura.web.shared.GwtKuraException: 
ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT
at Unknown.tg(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.Bg(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.Sfc(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.Xfc(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.hdb(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.ddb(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.Bbb(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.jcb(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.sr(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.Gr(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.<anonymous>(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.Ch(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.Fh(<anonymous>)
at Unknown.<anonymous>(<anonymous>)
```

Following the other steps (in documentation) and trying to connect it gives the following exception in kura console :

```
   org.eclipse.kura.KuraConnectException: "Connection failed. Cannot connect"
    at org.eclipse.kura.core.data.transport.mqtt.MqttDataTransport.connect(MqttDataTransport.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.kura.core.data.DataServiceImpl.connect(DataServiceImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.kura.web.server.GwtStatusServiceImpl.connectDataService(GwtStatusServiceImpl.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.kura.web.server.OsgiRemoteServiceServlet.service(OsgiRemoteServiceServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceRuntimeImpl$LegacyServlet.service(HttpServiceRuntimeImpl.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:100)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:664)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:650)
    ... 1 more
```

Solutions I have tried:

1. The broker url has the port 8883 and an mqtts protocol
2. the value Lwt.retain is set to false
3. the value for storage-alias and topic.context.account-name is same.

But nothing works.

Kura version : 3.0.0
Device : Linux Machine

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please be sure to follow the directions in the documentation exactly. For example, did you convert the private key to PKCS8 format? The error you are seeing in the web UI is typically due to an unexpected input.

Comment: @DavidWoodard- yes i have converted the private key to pkcs8 format no luck. the eclipse now give a bad_certificate exception.

Comment: is your certificate active? can u make sure u attached the policy that allow the action u are trying to do like allow connect/publish?
Also there are few things aws mqtt doesn't support and will break the connection if any of unsupported feature is requested check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html for the things not supported

Comment: Did you ever solved it, I have the same issue?